# how can write innerHTML to ioen jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to Open new JSP page(Form) on click on this link
New Employee Registraion ...

and open in same window on div section i write following code :

```
document.getElementById("article").load="registerForm.do";
```

But it Open in new Page I want to open in given div Section 
suggest me what can i do...

Comment: Sorry But i don't have any knowledge of J query please suggest me on my given way its vary ease for me ..thank you

Comment: I want to Open new JSP page(Form) on click on this link
<a href="registerForm.do" onclick="divload()">New Employee Registraion ...</a> 

and open in same window on div section i write following code :

    document.getElementById("article").load="registerForm.do";

But it Open in new Page I want to open in given div Section 
suggest me what can i do...

Comment: `<a href="registerForm.do">` will open a new page. do `<a href="#" id="showForm">` instead, and use `onclick` event to show the registration form

Comment: i was Done this also Bur It Dont do anything ...

Comment: check my updated answer below and **make sure** you have install JQuery properly

Comment: joshi is there any other way becouse it cant work

Comment: yes but i dont have any knowledge of jquery

Answer (score 2):

use JQuery for this, and you task is even simpler:

```
<script>
    $("#showForm").click(function(){
        $("#article").load("registerForm.do");
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="showForm">New Employee Registraion</a>
```

Please check [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) on how to install JQuery.

If you don't want to use JQuery, then you have to write the form manually:

```
var form="<form><table border='1'>"+
         "<tr>"+
         "<td>Registration Form</td>"+
         "</tr>"+
         "<tr>"+
         "<td>And so on...</td>"+
         "</tr>"+
         "</table></form>"

document.getElementById("article").innerHTML=form;
```

Comment: not Jigar. did you include JQuery script in your page?

Comment: You can find a tutorial for jQuery here: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/